# Measuring Performance of group by clause in mysql 5.7.*

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I recently  needed to find count all the users in the Mysql as per there country which are active.

Table schema is as

```
under.



| Field                   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |

| country_id              | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |

| user_id                 | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |

| uuid                    | varchar(40) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |

| active                  | bit(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
```

Note:User can be memeber of multiple country.

My Query for this calculation is as under

```
select count(*) as count,country_id from user_country where active=true group by (country_id);
```

I can solve the same problem using  subqueries. But i need to know is group by faster then subqueries if yes then why?

Comment: Speed of queries do most often depend on the structure of the database, indexes and data-size, so is hard to say if one query is faster than another without knowing that. You could try to fill the db with some data and run some tests, remember to flush query cache between runs. You can also try explain <your query> to see how the db will run it and how much it costs to run

Comment: what subquery ?

Answer (score 0):

- If there is an index on country_id:

MySQL will use this to optimize your group by. This is the fastest option if you want the count for all countries. It is also the fastest if you want a count for only one country or a few.

Do not use a subquery like:

```
SELECT c.country_id, (SELECT count(*) FROM users u WHERE u.country_id=c.country_id)
FROM countries c
```

This is more work, as the subquery will have to be executed for each country. This has no advantage here.

- If there is no index on country_id

In this case MySQL will have to read the whole table and use a sort to group by country_id. This is slower than using the index, but for an occasional reporting query it would be okay, same if results are cached and you run the query once a day, etc.

Without an index, using a dependent subquery would be a lot worse, as the whole table would have to be read and filtered for each country. This would be terrible.

Now, since both user_id and country_id are marked "PRI" index, I don't know if your PK is (country_id,user_id) or the other way around. If it is (country_id,user_id) then you already have an index on country. If it is (user_id,country_id) then you don't... and this would be a weird schema, btw.

Comment: (country_id,user_id) are composite primary key and i am searching using  country key  which is foreign key from country table,hence i have index on country_id. So your saying group by is efficient then subquery.

Comment: Yes group by will be more efficient.